# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined in reactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying out an example in reactJS where I'm displaying a list of records and delete them.Refresh the list after each delete. I saw many questions raised by this error heading, but nothing worked with me.

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
        loadCommentsFromServer: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.props.listUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    this.setState({data: data});
                }.bind(this),
                error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
                }.bind(this),
                cache: false
            });
        },
        getInitialState: function () {
            return {data: []};
        },
        componentDidMount: function () {
            this.loadCommentsFromServer();
        },
        onClickingDelete: function() {
            alert('Upper layer on click delete called');
            this.loadCommentsFromServer();
        },
        render: function () {
            return (
                    <div className="commentBox">
                        <h1>Static web page</h1>
                        <CommentList data={this.state.data} onClickingDelete={this.onClickingDelete}  />


                    </div>
            );
        }
    });


    var CommentList = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            if (this.props.data != '') {
                var commentNodes = this.props.data.content.map(function (comment) {

                    return (
                            <div className="comment" key={comment.id}>
                                <h2 className="commentpageName">
                                    {comment.pageName}
                                </h2>

                                <p> {comment.pageContent} </p>

                                <DeleteButton deleteUrl={'/delete/' + comment.id} onClickingDelete={this.props.onClickingDelete}/>

                            </div>
                    );
                });
            }
            return (
                <div className="commentList">
                    {commentNodes}
                </div>
            );
        }
    });

    var DeleteButton = React.createClass({
        onClickingDelete: function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.props.deleteUrl,
                type: 'delete',
                success: function () {
                    alert('Successfully deleted');
                    this.props.onClickingDelete();
                }.bind(this),
                error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                   console.error(this.props.deleteUrl, status, err.toString());
                }.bind(this),
                cache: false
            });

        },
        render: function() {
            return (
                <button name={this.props.deleteUrl} onClick={this.onClickingDelete}>Delete</button>
            );
        }
    });


    ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox listUrl="/list/"/>, 
document.getElementById('content'));
```

On page load, I'm getting

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

in the CommentList's line call to DeleteButton. Wondering how "this" can go undefined

Comment: probably because you are deleting the element. your whole component is removed.. but then you are on the callback saying this.props.something. try creating a pointer to your this to call.

Comment: @John, that was working without "onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit}" in comment list component. Removed  that line to avoid confusion. I'm getting the above error on page load. Sorry for that. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use array.map, **this** is undefined and undergoes the normal resolution for **this** in javascript. In strict mode, it'll stay undefined.

- Non-strict mode: **this** resolves to Window

  ```
  > [1].map(function(test) {console.log(this)});
  > [object Window]
  ```
- Strict mode: **this** resolves to undefined

  ```
  > 'use strict'; [1].map(function(test) {console.log(this)});
  > undefined
  ```

There are different ways to bind it to the current object.

- Using map.thisArg

  ```
  this.props.data.content.map(function(comment) { ... }, this);
  ```
- Using bind

  ```
  this.props.data.content.map(function(comment) { ... }).bind(this);
  ```
- Using an arrow function

  ```
  this.props.data.content.map(comment => { ... });
  ```
- Using a variable

  ```
  var that = this;
  this.props.data.content.map(function(comment) 
      { ... onClickingDelete={that.props.onClickingDelete} ... });
  ```

Sources:

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to map, it will be passed to
>   callback when invoked, for use as its this value. Otherwise, the value
>   undefined will be passed for use as its this value.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
>
> In strict mode, the value of this remains at whatever it's set to when
>   entering the execution context. If it's not defined, it remains
>   undefined.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this